# JMeter 5.4.1 – HTTP Sampler – Only runs 14 loops/Iterations when using fixed Thread and Loop numbers that are greater than 14 iterations

Tags: multithreading, jmeter

Test:  Thread Group A with a Single HTTP Sampler:

- It uses JMeter Properties for Thread and Loop number values
  -No Duration or Thread LifeTimes are set just ramp up..
  -The values are in defined in the Test Plan UDV.’s or with Thread and Loop numbers being initially defined in external  user.properties files, and are manipulated at runtime via a setUpThreadGroup before the TG with issues here.

Number of Threads: ${__P(My_Number_Of_Threads)} – can be varied at runtime by setUpThreadGroup
Ramp-up: ${My_Ramp_Up_Time} – set to 0
Loop: ${__P(My_Loop_Count)} – can be varied at runtime by setUpThreadGroup

Using  a My_Loop_Count = 5 :
`enter code here`(1-2 etc = ThreadNumber-SamplerNumber)
`enter code here`1 Thread: 1-1:1-5      = 5 iterations as expected
`enter code here`2 Threads: 1-1:1-5  2-1:2-5    = 10 iterations as expected
`enter code here`3 Threads: 1-1:1-5  2-1:2-4 NO 2-5 3-1:3-5 = 14 **NOT** 15 iterations
`enter code here`4 Threads: 1-1:1-4 NO 1-5 2-1:2-3 NO 2-4:2-5 3-1:3-4 NO 3-5  4-1:4-3  = 14 **NOT** 20 iterations run

Using a My_Loop_Count = 25, **again** it runs **only 14 iterations**.

1. Any ideas as to why this is happening? It is not time related, but iteration somehow (I even checked the .jmx via Notepad to hunt for my elusive 14, but none existed).
   **UPDATE** - the issue was a csv data file element with 14 items in it! Now set to 'rewind on end of file'

- reason: org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterStopThreadException: All records in the CSV file have been passed.

2. To aid in a more in depth hunting in the future, is there a way to see the actual runtime  ThreadGroup's **Thread Properties** values that are being set/used to console?

Answer (score 0):

We cannot state anything meaningful without seeing how do you "manipulate at runtime via a setUpThreadGroup" and how do the properties look like, you can try adding a [Debug Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) to see the effective values.

I would recommend checking [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging), it normally contains entries regarding threads start/stop events and if you enable debug logging you will see what's going on under the hood

Also be aware that [according to JMeter Best Practices you should always be using the latest version of JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#use_latest_version) so consider upgrading to [JMeter 5.5](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-5-5) (or whatever is the latest version available at [JMeter Downloads page](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi)) on next available opportunity

Comment: Hi Dimitri, as I updated post you'd already responsed - my first question was user stupidity. I'd missed a Recycle on EOF! 

With regards question 2 are there any JMeter methods that can be called in a JSR223 element to get and potentially manipulate a ThreadGroup's 'Thread Properties' values?